# htaccess multilanguage in codoforum script

Tags: .htaccess

I installed a codoforum for my project and now I want to make it  multi language
I did all the language switching in code and now I'm left with implementing it to a link.

Here is their htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options +Indexes
RewriteEngine on

# if your app is in a subfolder
#RewriteBase /my_app/ 

# test string is a valid files
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
# test string is a valid directory
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$   index.php?lang=ru&u=/$1    [NC,L,QSA] #My lang variable
# with QSA flag (query string append),
# forces the rewrite engine to append a query string part of the
# substitution string to the existing string, instead of replacing it.

</IfModule>
```

**Question:**

Can I some how get my language variable in the $u var
RewriteRule ^(.*)$   index.php?&u= /**mylangvar**/ $1

My link looks like this

category/general-discussions
I want it to look like this

**langvar**/category/general-discussions

If I disable pretty urls

/index.php?u=/category/general-discussions

Answer (score 0):

I did it myself, sorry for dumb question. 
Here is what I changed

```
RewriteRule ^(lv|en|ru)/(.*)$   index.php?lang=$1&u=/$2    [NC,L,QSA]
```